# How to extract ugly data from dictionary in python

Tags: python, dictionary, extract, assert

I am trying to write tests for my api, my response gets me ugly dictionary with only one value and lots of information in it, including list that i need to assert:

```
{'data': OrderedDict([('count', 2), ('next', None), ('previous', None), ('results', [OrderedDict([('id', 1), ('uuid', '345cd6a7-69d2-4e35-808c-7bbfbee0ed66'), ('created_at', '2021-07-23T15:51:18.619102Z'), ('updated_at', '2021-07-23T15:51:18.619122Z'), ('deleted', False), ('name', 'Vegan'), ('address', ''), ('city', None), ('postal_code', None), ('country', None), ('phone', None), ('email', None)]), OrderedDict([('id', 2), ('uuid', 'e6a7ce08-259e-4a5b-bf96-2f311382b8ac'), ('created_at', '2021-07-23T15:51:18.619359Z'), ('updated_at', '2021-07-23T15:51:18.619373Z'), ('deleted', False), ('name', 'Dessert'), ('address', ''), ('city', None), ('postal_code', None), ('country', None), ('phone', None), ('email', None)])])]), 'code': 200, 'message': None}
```

I want to assert it with my serializer data which returns me a list which is the same as one list in my response dictionary value:

```
[OrderedDict([('id', 1), ('uuid', '345cd6a7-69d2-4e35-808c-7bbfbee0ed66'), ('created_at', '2021-07-23T15:51:18.619102Z'), ('updated_at', '2021-07-23T15:51:18.619122Z'), ('deleted', False), ('name', 'Vegan'), ('address', ''), ('city', None), ('postal_code', None), ('country', None), ('phone', None), ('email', None)]), OrderedDict([('id', 2), ('uuid', 'e6a7ce08-259e-4a5b-bf96-2f311382b8ac'), ('created_at', '2021-07-23T15:51:18.619359Z'), ('updated_at', '2021-07-23T15:51:18.619373Z'), ('deleted', False), ('name', 'Dessert'), ('address', ''), ('city', None), ('postal_code', None), ('country', None), ('phone', None), ('email', None)])]
```

if I could somehow extract that list from this dictionary it would be great, any help appreciated.

Comment: So you just need `data.results`?

Answer (score 0):

Right from the repl:

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> api = {'data': OrderedDict([('count', 2), ('next', None), ('previous', None), ('results', [OrderedDict([('id', 1), ('uuid', '345cd6a7-69d2-4e35-808c-7bbfbee0ed66'), ('created_at', '2021-07-23T15:51:18.619102Z'), ('updated_at', '2021-07-23T15:51:18.619122Z'), ('deleted', False), ('name', 'Vegan'),('address', ''), ('city', None), ('postal_code', None), ('country', None), ('phone', None), ('email', None)]), OrderedDict([('id', 2), ('uuid', 'e6a7ce08-259e-4a5b-bf96-2f311382b8ac'), ('created_at', '2021-07-23T15:51:18.619359Z'), ('updated_at', '2021-07-23T15:51:18.619373Z'), ('deleted', False), ('name', 'Dessert'), ('address', ''), ('city', None), ('postal_code', None), ('country', None), ('phone', None), ('email', None)])])]), 'code': 200, 'message': None}
>>> api
{'data': OrderedDict([('count', 2), ('next', None), ('previous', None), ('results', [OrderedDict([('id', 1), ('uuid', '345cd6a7-69d2-4e35-808c-7bbfbee0ed66'), ('created_at', '2021-07-23T15:51:18.619102Z'), ('updated_at', '2021-07-23T15:51:18.619122Z'), ('deleted', False), ('name', 'Vegan'), ('address', ''), ('city', None), ('postal_code', None), ('country', None), ('phone', None), ('email', None)]), OrderedDict([('id', 2), ('uuid', 'e6a7ce08-259e-4a5b-bf96-2f311382b8ac'), ('created_at', '2021-07-23T15:51:18.619359Z'), ('updated_at', '2021-07-23T15:51:18.619373Z'), ('deleted', False), ('name', 'Dessert'), ('address', ''), ('city', None), ('postal_code', None), ('country', None), ('phone', None), ('email', None)])])]), 'code': 200, 'message':None}
>>> api['data']['results']
[OrderedDict([('id', 1), ('uuid', '345cd6a7-69d2-4e35-808c-7bbfbee0ed66'), ('created_at', '2021-07-23T15:51:18.619102Z'), ('updated_at', '2021-07-23T15:51:18.619122Z'), ('deleted', False), ('name', 'Vegan'), ('address', ''), ('city', None), ('postal_code', None), ('country', None), ('phone', None), ('email', None)]), OrderedDict([('id', 2), ('uuid', 'e6a7ce08-259e-4a5b-bf96-2f311382b8ac'), ('created_at', '2021-07-23T15:51:18.619359Z'), ('updated_at', '2021-07-23T15:51:18.619373Z'), ('deleted', False), ('name', 'Dessert'), ('address', ''), ('city', None), ('postal_code', None), ('country', None), ('phone', None), ('email', None)])]
```

Comment: Thank you for help, this was exactly what i needed.